intermittent toilet tank overfill
I have an intermittent toilet tank overfill problem: the float system doesn't shut off the water supply properly although the float doesn't seem to be blocked anywhere. When the float rises, sometimes it doesn't cut off the water supply and hence gets submerged. Sometimes it cuts off the water supply and then reopens 1 to 30 seconds later. Maybe the presence of this delay is specific to the cause ?
The very first time the problem occurred, some months ago, it was not even after a flush. The tank was full, I was at my desk and alone in the apartment, and the system started to leak.
I temporarily fixed the problem twice for at least 1 week by :

circulating the water quickly through the pipes

cleaning the membrane (that was changed less than a year ago and has no hole in it) and flipping the rubber that plugs the tiny hole that gets blocked when the float rises


But the problem always came back. Now it may occurs several times per day of just once every other day.
Other toilets' owners in the building don't experience this problem. I soaked the piece with the tiny hole in the vinegar but it didn't fix the problem. I get the 6L tank filled in 45 seconds which seems to mean that the water pressure is normal. The water here is not hard.
If I push the float downward when the tank is full, I get some air bubble coming from the bottom, is it normal ?
I guess replacing the whole system will fix the problem but I would like to understand the cause before doing it.
Thank you


Good chance the float has a leak, air bubbles coming from might be a sign.  Most insides of a toilet tank come in a kit and are usually cheap, ~10 to 20 dollars.  Small chance the float is not adjusted right also.

It could simply be that the seat for the rubber membrane is worn, an internal crack, friction in the float pivot/slide or a waterlogged float. However, as @crip659 states, replacing the whole fill valve assembly is easy, and kits are advertised for US$8 to 20.

Note that if it's a rented apartment, you want the landlord to get a plumber to resolve it; don't do anything without their approval. You don't want the liability if something goes wrong.

Thank you for your answers ! :-)
I just added the photo that I forgot.  The vertical pipe is actually made of 2 pipes so that the water is released in the tank at the bottom. That's where the air bubble come from.
@crisp659
Actually I think it's is normal to get air bubbles there, as long as it's normal that air enters in the system when it is shut off by the float.

@DrMoishe Pippik Could you precise which rubber membrane you talk about ?

@keshlam Thanks for the reminder, it's indeed a rented apartment.

Finally I ordered a whole new float system, but I changed just the shutting part and it resolved the problem. I still don't know what was the exact cause. The tiny hole is similar in the old and new piece. For reference for people of the future, the system here is a "Siamp compact 99B".
